# How can i make cin.ignore to take any non integer value to be an delimiter

Tags: c++

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   int main(){
      int a, b;
      
      std::cin >> a;
      std::cin.ignore(3, '/');
      std::cin >> b;
      std::cout << a << " " << b;
      
   return 0;
   }
```

How can I change my code so that the separators do not have to be Slash characters “/” but any separator that is not an integer number.

Comment: There's a number of different solutions for that problem, `std::ignore()` isn't one of them.

Comment: Depending on what your underlying problem really is, it might be as simple to read line by line and then attempt to convert the string to an integer. If the conversion fails, read next line and try the conversion again. And so on.

Comment: Under normal conditions, if `std::cin >> a` is successful (always check the stream state after a read!), it will have already stopped reading on a non-integer character, so just `ignore()` the next character if it is not a space (use `peek()` to check that). The code appears to be ignoring *up to 3 characters before a separator*, and your question implies that those 3 characters are digits, so why not just use `>>` to read them into a dummy integer variable? What does the input actually look like?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use [`ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) for that.

Instead use a loop to [`peek`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek) at and [fetch](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) the next character until the character matches your condition to stop "ignoring" character.

The characters you read that you want to "ignore", just don't do anything with them.

Comment: The hard part is going to be telling integers from floating point numbers.